# Adding a working <a> inside a Keyframed Figure animation

Tags: html, css, anchor, figure

#### Background:

I'm trying to create a rotating image banner with several links, each link being different. The `FIGURE` are set inside a `DIV` which is nested inside another `DIV` for centering and positioning purposes.

#### Current JSFiddle:

[Available here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfebyf93/) without WebKits.

#### Problem:

Although I tried with several combinations, inside the markup and CSS, never does it trigger the anchor in any of the images (I have not set any effect on hovering yet, not to confuse the code). I deleted the anchors so you can see the base code before the tests I did. It functions now as perfect Pic Slideshow, yes, but that is not the intent.

#### Need:

To know what to do with an `A` tag for it to work on each of the images separately, in order to transform the PIC SLIDESHOW into an alternative to a Slider.

#### Code type restrictions:

I do not wish to use a JQuery in the solution, only CSS, HTML and the **smallest JavaScript possible if everything else fails**

Many Thanks

Comment: This sounds very difficult without JavaScript. It may be possible but not sure. Out of curiosity, why avoid scripts?

Comment: I don't know JAVASCRIPT (don't have enough time to learn it) and I like to control what I'm writing as opposed to copy paste code from the web, I like to keep my pages without as many languages as possible and my server hosting without additional files (this if we were discussing JQUERY). If many people say it's impossible without JS, then I may consider keeping only JQUERY out of the equation, but I would like a guru's help to see if this can be done without JS.

Comment: Totally understand your concerns. I will say this is a perfect fit for JavaScript and a solution without it is very likely to be a hack. If you're anything like me, I would prefer my app to have a small bit of code that I may not fully understand, rather than an unstable hack. But likewise would love to see if there's a non-js solution.

Comment: One interesting thing I found out, is that if I place the sequence like this `<figure><a ...><img></a></figure>`, no matter in which one of the six `<figure>`, all images lock on the the same anchor, which works if I have a single destination link and I'm just slideshowing images about the link reference... which tells me the problem can be on `keyframes` somehow...

Comment: Ok, my request is now updated...

Comment: don't understand not even a js hint? :-(